# ActionScript 3.0 Array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a working array and a loop with this array. I just have a trace action in my loop so I know that it is looping. My question is how would I be able to display the next image array when the right/wrong answer is selected.  My code is below and any help would be appreciated :)

```
var characterArray:Array = new Array(); 
characterArray[0] = [pirateboy, pirategirl, pig]; //pig is the ans
characterArray[1] = [pirategirl, pirategirl ,pirateboy]; //pirateboy is the ans
characterArray[2] = [pirategirl, pirateboy, pirateboy]; //pirategirl is the ans 
characterArray[3] = [parrot, snowman, parrot]; //snowman is the ans

pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightanswer); 

 function rightanswer (event:MouseEvent){ 
 if (MovieClip(event.target) == characterArray[0][2])
{ 
gotoAndStop(3)

} 

}

pirateboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightanswer1); 

function rightanswer1 (event:MouseEvent){ 
if (MovieClip(event.target) == characterArray[1][2])
{ 
gotoAndStop(3)

} 

}
```

for(var i:int = 0; i<3; i++) {

trace("game");

} //loops array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs some restructuring.

Store the index of the active characterArray subarray.

```
var characterArray:Array = new Array();
characterArray[0] = [pirateboy, pirategirl, pig]; //pig is the ans
characterArray[1] = [pirategirl, pirategirl ,pirateboy]; //pirateboy is the ans
characterArray[2] = [pirategirl, pirateboy, pirateboy]; //pirategirl is the ans 
characterArray[3] = [parrot, snowman, parrot]; //snowman is the ans

pig.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCharacterClick);
pirateboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCharacterClick);
pirateGirl.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCharacterClick);
snowman.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onCharacterClick);

var currentQuestion:int = 0;

function onCharacterClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(currentQuestion)
    {
        case 0:
            if(event.target == pig)
            {
                currentQuestion++;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if(event.target == pirateboy)
            {
                currentQuestion++;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(event.target == pirategirl)
            {
                currentQuestion++;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            if(event.target == snowman)
            {
                currentQuestion++;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This stores the current set of characters. You can access that specific array using `characterArray[currentQuestion]`. If you wanted to display each character choice, you can loop through the current characterArray like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < characterArray[currentQuestion].length; i++)
{
    //add characterArray[currentQuestion][i] to the displaylist
}
```